# How to save image in ImageView to DB and recall the image when activity starts

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have an app where the user draws a picture and returns to my ImageView in my app.  The image is displayed and working. I then have a save button to save the entire form (with the Image), but when I click save and reopen the app the text is displayed but not the image.

Here is the code to enter the text in the database:

MainActivity.Class

```
EditText myName;
ImageView myImage;
EditText myJob;
byte[] myProf;
.... 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    personID = getIntent().getIntExtra(FragmentJob.KEY_EXTRA_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);

    DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MYForm/";
    pic_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    StoredPath = DIRECTORY + pic_name + ".png";

....

myName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMyName);
myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myProfImage);
myJob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myJobAgeWorked);

....

dbHelper = new MyDBHelper(this);

    if (personID > 0) {
        saveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        rs = dbHelper.getPerson(personID);
        rs.moveToFirst();
        String myNameIs = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.MY_NAME));
        myProf = rs.getBlob(rs.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.MY_PROFILE));

   .....

int myAge = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.MY_JOB));
        if (!rs.isClosed()) {
            rs.close();
        }

        myName.setText(cmyNameIs);
        myName.setFocusable(false);
        myName.setClickable(false);

//I don't know if the below code works or not for "myImage"

        myImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(myProf + StoredPath));
        myImage.setFocusable(true);
        myImage.setClickable(false);

        myJob.setEnabled(true);
        myJob.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        myJob.setClickable(true);

....

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.saveButton:
            persistPerson();
            return;
        case R.id.editButton:
            saveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            myName.setEnabled(true);
            myName.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            myName.setClickable(true);

            myImage.setEnabled(false);
            myImage.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            myImage.setClickable(false);

            myJob.setEnabled(true);
            myJob.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            myJob.setClickable(true);

....

//This is where I think I am going wrong

public void persistPerson() {
    if (personID > 0) {
        if (dbHelper.updatePerson(personID,
                myName.getText().toString(), //WORKS
                StoredPath.getBytes().toString(), //Not Sure that this is 
                                                    correct
                Integer.parseInt(myJob.getText().toString()))) {

....

} else {
        if (dbHelper.insertPerson(
                myName.getText().toString(), //WORKS
                StoredPath.getBytes().toString(), //Not Sure that this is 
                                                    correct
                Integer.parseInt(myJob.getText().toString()))) {

....

private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

 ***EDIT***
//persmission method.
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have read or write permission
    int writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );

    }
}

//THEN BELOW CODE IS FROM THE DRAWING PAD

mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("tag", "Panel Saved");
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSignature.save(view, StoredPath);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File f = new File(StoredPath);
            ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.editMyName);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 620, 620, false));
        }
    });
```

This will show the text entered and image when the user selects get "drawing" button and drew a picture.  After this step when hitting the "save" button the text is saved and the image not.

The error is:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [B@cdfe4dd/storage/emulated/0/MYForm/20170615_114018.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

For my MyDBHelper.class

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SQLiteExample.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public static final String PERSON_TABLE_NAME = "person";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String MY_NAME = "myfullname";
public static final String MY_PROFILE = "myprofileimage";

....

public ExampleDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME +
                    "(" + PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    MY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                    MY_PROFILE + " BLOB, " +
                    MY_JOB + " INTEGER)"
    );
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertPerson(String mynameis,
                            String myprofimage,
                            int jobnumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(MY_NAME, mynameis);
    contentValues.put(MY_PROFILE, myprofimage);
    contentValues.put(MY_JOB, jobnumber);

    db.insert(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

 public int numberOfRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updatePerson(Integer id,
                            String mynameis,
                            String smyprofimage,
                            int jobnumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MY_NAME, customername);
    contentValues.put(MY_PROFILE, signature);
    contentValues.put(MY_JOB, jobnumber);
    db.update(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return true;
}

.....
```

I hope i made sense here :-)
Could some help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have that in my manifest file as well is in my MainActivity class.  I have edited my question

Comment: I can browes to that location on my phone and i can see the files

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can save image as byte[] in database. take bitmap from your imageview and convert it to byte[] and then save in database.

    ex : 

    yourimageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = yourimageView.getDrawingCache();

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] imageData=stream.toByteArray();


now you can save imageData in database
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do i incorporate that in my code?  I tried just now but does not work.

Comment: on save button click